# Is there a way to have a toggled legend item save its state on refresh?

Tags: highcharts

Is there currently a way to have a legend item save its state on refresh?  For example, I have a graph that has 3 lines: a, b, and c.  I toggle off line c so it doesn't show on the graph.  Currently when refreshing the page, a, b, and c will show on the graph again.  Is there a way to have it remember to turn off c?

Comment: To store information across a refresh, you would probably need to use cookies or a database backend.

Answer (score 3):

Use `localStorage` feature to store current state of the chart series visibility. You need to change the state of your local storage position when clicking on legend item, so just use the `plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick` handler, and then on every chart `load` event, set your series visibility basing on the stored information.

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var series = this.series;
        // If there is no legend items visibility flags saved in local storage, save them.
        if (!localStorage.legendItems) {
          let legend = []
          series.forEach(function(series) {
            legend.push(series.visible)
          })
          localStorage.legendItems = legend.toString()
         //
        } else {
          let legend = localStorage.legendItems.split(',')
          let legendBooleans = []
          legend.forEach(function(elem) {
            var isTrueSet = (elem === 'true')
            legendBooleans.push(isTrueSet)
          })
          legendBooleans.forEach(function(state, i) {
            series[i].update({
                visible: state
            })
          })
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      events: {
        legendItemClick: function() {
          var series = this.chart.series
          var index = this.index
          var legend = localStorage.legendItems.split(',')
          var legendBooleans = []
          legend.forEach(function(elem) {
            var isTrueSet = (elem === 'true')
            legendBooleans.push(isTrueSet)
          })
          // toggle series visibility flag and override it in local storage
          legendBooleans[index] = !legendBooleans[index]
          localStorage.legendItems = legendBooleans.toString()
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

If you have any questions, just ask.

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/os961gke/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load