# Any solution to reduce loading time when using localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, local-storage

I find one [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313462/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-toggled-legend-item-save-its-state-on-refresh) to save selected LegendItems by using localStorage.

but when the data is too large, the loading speed of chart becomes slow,

here is my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9100bo/rb6jyzsq/9/)

```
events: {
  load: function() { ... }
```

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Looks like the very slow part is `series[i].update()`. Each iteration takes about 350ms, there are 90 of them, and that's only CPU time. It has nothing to do with LocalStorage, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same approach as in the click event handler - redraw your chart after a loop, not in every iteration.

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    ...
    if (!localStorage.legendItems) {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
      legendBooleans.forEach(function(state, i) {
        series[i].update({
          visible: state
        }, false);
      })
                
      this.redraw();
    }
  } 
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zufLce9h/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Comment: I see, I will use only use redraw after the for loop,Thank you!